# Como chamar nome de coluna de outra classe no WebGrid MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

EU tenho essa *view* `Listar.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<ODM>
@{
    var idGrid = "grid" + this.ViewBag.IdParameters ?? string.Empty;
    var grid = new IBM.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(id: idGrid, rowsPerPage: this.RowsPerPage, ajaxUpdateContainerId: idGrid);
    var columns = new WebGridColumn[] {
        grid.Column("Codigo", ODMResources.Codigo),
        grid.Column("DataEmissao", ODMResources.DataEmissao),
        **grid.Column("Iniciativa.Codigo"**,
            canSort: false,
            header: IniciativaResources.Titulo),
        grid.Column("DescricaoChefes", ODMResources.ProjectChief),
        grid.Column("Modelo.Codigo",
            canSort: false,
            header: ModeloResources.ModeloReferencia),
        //grid.Column("DescricaoResponsaveis", ODMResources.ProjectResponsible),
        grid.Column("Causal", ODMResources.Causal),
        grid.Column("Estado", ODMResources.Estado),

}
@grid.GetHtmlExtended(this.Model, this.RowsCount, page: this, columns: columns)
```

Tanto `Iniciativa.Codigo` quanto `Modelo.Codigo` não funcionam. Aparece o erro:

> Column "Iniciativa.Codigo" does not exist.

Qual a melhor forma de chamar a descrição de uma coluna de outra classe no WebGrid?

Obs.: Iniciativa e Modelo tem relacionamento com ODM.

Answer (score 1):

Consigo acessar métodos de outra classe de forma similar a que você utiliza, porém com algumas modificações no código, segue exemplo:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.List, canSort: false, canPage: false);

var htmlString = grid.GetHtml
(
    tableStyle: "webGrid table table-striped table-hover",
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "DataTable" },
    headerStyle: "header",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",

    columns: grid.Columns
    (
        grid.Column("Id", "Código", canSort: false),
        grid.Column("Modelo.Nome", "Nome", canSort: false),
        grid.Column
        (
            "Editar",
            format: (item) =>
                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' id='btnDetalhes'" +
                "onclick='editar("
                    + @item.Id +
                ")'>"
                + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> Editar </button>",
            canSort: false
        )
    )
);
```